# Laravel 5.1. Отключить проверку CSRF-токена по определенным маршрутам

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

На данный момент проверка *CSRF* отключена в kernel. Однако этот способ меня не устраивает, подскажите альтернативные возможности которые реализованы в *Laravel 5.1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В *Laravel 5.1*, Вы можете отключить проверку *CSRF*-токена определенного маршрута добавив его (маршрут) в поле `$except` в *VerifyCsrfToken middleware*:

**файл - App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //тут прописываем маршруты которые хотим исключить
        'customRoute/*',
    ];
}
```